# Determining start/end times of intervals from individual transaction records

Tags: sql, vb.net, loops, ms-access

how can i insert data from table1 to table2 i am using MS Access.
this is what i wanted to have.

Table 1

```
|id|    date    |  time |
| 3|  7/22/2017 |  8:00 |
| 3|  7/22/2017 | 17:00 |
| 4|  7/22/2017 |  8:00 |
| 4|  7/22/2017 | 12:00 |
| 4|  7/22/2017 | 13:00 |
| 4|  7/22/2017 | 17:00 |
```

i want to have it like this on new table
Table 2

```
|id|working date|time-in|time-out|time-in|time-out|
| 3|  7/22/2017 |  8:00 |        |       | 17:00  |
| 4|  7/22/2017 |  8:00 | 12:00  | 13:00 | 17:00  |
```

Is it possible on a loop or this is a query? Please help

Comment: Being possible and being possible in MS Access are two different things.  This type of query is pretty challenging in MS Access.

Comment: yes it is. i have been spending a week on this. :(

Comment: Multiple repeating identical columns - `timein1`, `timein2` - is a bad design as it indicates you missed a 1:m relationship.  As a timeclock type app, it is very limiting because emergencies, doctor's appointments etc cant be accommodated with 2 and only 2 in-out pairs per day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a query that does an unequal self-join to assign sequential values to the rows grouped by [id] and [date]

```sql
SELECT 
    t1.id,
    t1.date,
    t1.time,
    COUNT(*) AS seq
FROM
    Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN
    Table1 t2
        ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.date = t2.date AND t1.time >= t2.time
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.date, t1.time
```

which gives us

```
id  date        time      seq
--  ----------  --------  ---
 3  2017-07-22  08:00:00    1
 3  2017-07-22  17:00:00    2
 4  2017-07-22  08:00:00    1
 4  2017-07-22  12:00:00    2
 4  2017-07-22  13:00:00    3
 4  2017-07-22  17:00:00    4
```

Wrap that in a query that calculates a "tag" indicating 'in1', 'out1', 'in2', 'out2', etc.

```sql
SELECT
    [id],
    [date],
    [time],
    IIf([seq] Mod 2 = 1, "in", "out") & ([seq] + 1) \ 2 AS tag
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        t1.id,
        t1.date,
        t1.time,
        COUNT(*) AS seq
    FROM
        Table1 t1
        INNER JOIN
        Table1 t2
            ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.date = t2.date AND t1.time >= t2.time
    GROUP BY t1.id, t1.date, t1.time
)
```

producing

```
id  date        time      tag 
--  ----------  --------  ----
 3  2017-07-22  08:00:00  in1 
 3  2017-07-22  17:00:00  out1
 4  2017-07-22  08:00:00  in1 
 4  2017-07-22  12:00:00  out1
 4  2017-07-22  13:00:00  in2 
 4  2017-07-22  17:00:00  out2
```

Then wrap that whole thing in a crosstab query

```sql
TRANSFORM Min([time]) AS MinOftime
SELECT [id], [date]
FROM
(
    SELECT
        [id],
        [date],
        [time],
        IIf([seq] Mod 2 = 1, "in", "out") & ([seq] + 1) \ 2 AS tag
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            t1.id,
            t1.date,
            t1.time,
            COUNT(*) AS seq
        FROM
            Table1 t1
            INNER JOIN
            Table1 t2
                ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.date = t2.date AND t1.time >= t2.time
        GROUP BY t1.id, t1.date, t1.time
    )
)
GROUP BY [id], [date]
PIVOT [tag]
```

for the final result

```
id  date        in1       in2       out1      out2    
--  ----------  --------  --------  --------  --------
 3  2017-07-22  08:00:00            17:00:00          
 4  2017-07-22  08:00:00  13:00:00  12:00:00  17:00:00
```

Comment: Hi Gord thank you for your answer i really do appriciate it., but when i tried it on access as a query it dosen't work, does it mean i have to embed this on my vb.net codes?

Comment: @SamAlderete - Do you mean that you saved the query in Access and then tried to call that query from VB.NET? Also, what exactly do you mean by "it dosen't [sic] work"?

Comment: Hi Gord, Thank you very much. it seems it work now, :)

Comment: yes i did save the query, i wanted to call that query on vb.net.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to transfer a field to another field? like a cut and paste? using IIF

Comment: @SamAlderete - I'm not really sure what you're asking, but it sounds like a different question altogether. Please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), clearly explaining what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry if its not clear. What i wanted was to pass the value of out1 to out2 since there is no value for in2 and out2. If there is no in2 and out2 out1 should be automatically go to out2. Is that possible?